# Remove all permissions from all security groups Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I need to remove all the permissions in sharepoint to all security groups in Powershell.

First, I'm trying to do this in all groups and here's my code:

```
    $groups = $root.SiteGroups
    foreach($group in $groups)
    {

    }
```

I only found the way to add with roles like this, but I want to remove all.

```
  $spRoleAssignment = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($spGroup)
               $sproledefinition = $web.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"]
               $sproleassignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($sproledefinition)
```

thanks in advance.

Jordi

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all `RoleDefinitionBindings` from a SPRoleAssignment with [`RemoveAll()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.roledefinitionbindingcollection.removeall.aspx):

```
$sproleassignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.RemoveAll()
```